# zip in IronPython 2.7 and Python3.5

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a script that I want to execute both in Python3.5 and IronPython2.7.

The script is originally written with Python3 in mind, so I have some nested loops similar to the  code below :

```
myIter0 = iter(['foo','foo','bar','foo','spam','spam'])
myIter1 = iter(['foo','bar','spam','foo','spam','bar'])
myIter2 = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])

for a in myIter0:
    for b, c in zip(myIter1, myIter2):
        if a + b == 'foobar':
            print(c)
            break
```

Now if I run this in IronPython2.7 I don't get the same result because zip returns a list and not an iterator.

To circumvent this problem, I thought I would do :

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    from itertools import izip as _zip
else:
    _zip = zip

myIter0 = iter(['foo','foo','bar','foo','spam','spam'])
myIter1 = iter(['foo','bar','spam','foo','spam','bar'])
myIter2 = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])

for a in myIter0:
    for b, c in _zip(myIter1, myIter2):
        if a + b == 'foobar':
            print(c)
            break
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Maybe I'm still too sleep, but what's the problem with `zip` returning a list in python2? Or is it specific to IronPython?

Comment: The problem is that `zip(myIter1, myIter2)` uses all the items in `myIter1` and `myIter2` in Python2. The program doesn't reenter the nested `for` loop since `zip(myIter1, myIter2)` is an empty iterator after the first iteration of the main loop.

Comment: How about [`six.zip()`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/)?

Comment: @pzp, that's a good suggestion but I am working from IronPython in Grasshopper, so I am looking for a single file solutions. Thanks for introducing me to `six` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`builtins`](http://python-future.org/imports.html#imports-of-builtins) from the [future](http://python-future.org/quickstart.html#quick-start-guide) lib.

```
from builtins import zip
```

In python2 you get an `itertools.izip`  and in python3 you just get zip.

```
In [1]: from builtins import zip

In [2]: zip([1,2,3,4])
Out[2]: <itertools.izip at 0x7fa16c8496c8>

In [1]: from builtins import zip

In [2]: zip([1,2,3,4])
Out[2]: <zip at 0x7f13dfb9c188>
```

Comment: @JacquesGaudin, you have to install it `pip install future`,  if you want to write code for python2 and 3 then you should install it

Comment: Actually `from future_builtins import zip` works without installing future !

Comment: @JacquesGaudin, it will work in python2 but not in python3, there is no `future_builtins`.

Comment: yes but I have a `try` statment to import other functions anyway. So if I put it in there, I can catch the `ImportError` when running in Python3

Comment: @JacquesGaudin, yes but the point is python-future is batteries included it does the work for you. http://python-future.org/overview.html#code-examples

Comment: I use IronPython from Grasshopper to provide some geometry methods that I don't use otherwise, hence the `try` statement.

Answer (score 2):

That looks perfectly reasonable to me. A small modification will allow you to avoid the explicit version number check by doing

```
try:
    from itertools import izip as zip_
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    zip_ = zip
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have such a try statment at the beginning of my script to detect the availability of other functions so it would be easy to incorporate.

Answer (score -1):

For Python3.5 users,

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
B=[7,6,5,4,32,1]

In: c=list(zip(A,B))

In: print(c)

out: [(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(4,4),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1)]
```

Comment: This late answer doesn't relate to the question.